# System call 'open' mode not working

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, c

I am writing a simple code about opening a file with `O_CREAT | O_WDONLY | O_EXCL` flags. The code looks like this:

```
int fd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777);
```

It works well, except for the mode (permission) part. What ever I put in the others part, it always creates a file with `r-x`.

For example, the permission of the file created from the above code looks like this.

```
rwxrwxr-x.
```

This isn't `777` isn't it ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bits in the [`umask`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) of the current process are cleared when the file is created.  In this case, it looks like the umask is `0002` (no world write).  Call [`umask()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) before calling `open()` to change that.

Soapbox: please don't create world-writable files unless you're **really** sure that's what you want.  `umask` exists to save you and your users from exactly that type of vulnerability.